# Mistake Integer customized value Java

Tags: java, class, input, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

How can I read-in an integer in this following program? It doesn't work. It doesn't compile at the moment.

```
/**
 * Main class of the Java program. 
 * 
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

//...
class Scanner{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = in.nextInt();
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // we print a heading and make it bigger using HTML formatting
        System.out.println("<h4>-- Binaere Suche --</h4>");
        int anzahl = 0; int zahl;

    }
}
```

Comment: And then? Something is still missing.

Comment: ./Root/src/Main.java:23: error: int cannot be dereferenced
        zahl.Scan();
            ^
Note: ./Root/src/BinarySearchFactory.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: Under the println use
`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int zahl = sc.nextInt();` Remove the Scanner class (it's in java already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// This will print what you want but will not make it look bigger as it
// will get printed in console
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = in.nextInt();
 // we print a heading and make it bigger using HTML formatting
        System.out.println("<h4>--"+num+" --</h4>");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it compiles now.